# Laravel 5 CORS-issue vs. Ionic Angular

Tags: laravel, cordova, ionic-framework, cors

I am currently making an Ionic/Cordova-application with Laravel 5 as a Rest-server (my first time coding a PHP-server). 
With Postman all my Get/Post/Update/Delete-functions work on Laravel, and on clientside (Ionic Cordova). I am able to send data to http://postcatcher.in using [Chrome Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi). Without the plugin, I get this error:

[image]

Since this problem apparently only happens in development-mode (when testing client-side in browser), I assume it's alright to develop with the plugin.

When I try to send data to Laravel through Ionic Cordova, I get this error (even with the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin: 
[image]

I have tried multiple things, such as https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors, which just doesn't seem to work for me. Neither does suggestions in this forum, using CORS-middlewares. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-cors-headers-with-filters

I assume that this is a Laravel-issue, but I am not 100% sure.

To publish the server, I use
**php artisan serve**, giving it **localhost:8000**. 
For the application, I write: **ionic serve**, which gives it **localhost:8100**.

At last, this is the code I use to send data on Ionic-side:

```
.factory('userFactory', function($http, $q) {
 return{
    createuser : function(info) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('localhost:8000/users', info) 
        .success(function(response, status){
            deferred.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function() {
            console.log('SOMETHING WENT WRONG');
        });
                return deferred.promise;
  }

 }
})
```

**Any** help is really appreciated. Really stuck with this issue.

Comment: If it is just a PHP REST API you are building, I suggest [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) instead. Very lightweight version of Laravel. Less over head, faster etc

Comment: I will take that into consideration. Thanks! 
Just went with Laravel, because I think I need a real-time chat on the application - which I assume will be less problematic to make with Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I'm an absolute idiot. I just needed to write "http://" in front on the URL. Rookie mistake.
EDIT: I'll keep the question open for just half an hour, in case anyone has advice for me.